# Numpy Dot product of 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Experimenting with dot product is giving me some unexpected results:

```
a = np.array( [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ])
b = np.array([5, 6])
c = np.array((3,2))

x = np.dot(a, b)
x
array([17, 39])

y = np.dot(b,c)
y
27

z = np.dot(x,y,c)
[ 459 1053]
```

The last step is confusing, I was expecting to see a 2x2 matrix:

```
[ [1377, 918], [3159, 2106]]
```

Not sure what is wrong here...detailed calcs in this google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17yPHgYhHSW0N8FyBgaf9ya-am1b8LLVBWSjfK9ZGaTo/edit?usp=sharing

Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the docs?  The third argument is the `out`

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you could reveal the equation you want to calculate.

Comment: I have the answer, it was just confusion and bad reading of the doc on my end. The full set of matrices are in the google sheet link I provided. I was incorrectly multiplying three matrices, whereas the function dot (a, b, c) doesn't do that, as @hapulj pointed out. Appreciate the help!